# Constraints on generating valid covariance matrices for multivariate normal distributions

Tags: covariance-matrix, random-generation, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I am interested in randomly generating multivariate normal distributions (MVND) as the underlying probability function to generate instances for a data stream. I understand that to do so requires two things (i.e. a MVND is parameterized by two things):

1. A vector in the $n$-dimensional space representing where the MVND is centered; and
2. An $n \times n$ matrix representing the covariance of the distribution.

Step 1 is trivial to generate and I have no problems there. Step 2, however, presents some challenges that I am trying to overcome. At the moment I am generating random values $\in [0.0, 1.0]$ to populate the covariance matrix, $C$. From what I have found [online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) this process is subject to the following constraints:

1. $C_{ii}$ is equal to the variance of the $i$th random variable;
2. $C$ must be symmetric: $C_{ij} = C_{ji}$; and
3. $C$ must be positive definite: $z^TCz > 0 \text{ } \forall \text{ non-zero column vector }z\text{ of }n\text{ real numbers}$.

Constraint 3 seems to be the trickiest one to meet and was chosen so that the MVND's density function is "non-degenerate". I have been successful generating diagonal covariances matrices (described [here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/gaussians.pdf)) where $C_{ij} = C_{ji} = 0 \text{, }\forall i\neq j$, but this is a bit of a cheat. I would like to be able to fully simulate the full range of MVND and, eventually other multivariate distributions. I would like to know, then:

**Are my constraints correct?**

and

**Am I missing any constraints?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your constraints are correct (though I wouldn't really call the first one a constraint, necessarily...).

One way to generate symmetric positive semi-definite matrices is as follows: if $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$, then $X X^T \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is psd: $(X X^T)^T = X X^T$ so that it's symmetric, and $z^T X X^T z = \lVert X^T z \rVert^2 \ge 0$. So any way that you choose $X$ will give you a valid covariance $X X^T$, and indeed any psd matrix can be decomposed in such a way (e.g. the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)).

If you choose the entries of $X$ to be iid normal, for example, you get a [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution).

Answer (score 3):

Your constraints are correct.  This question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab).  The most intuitive solution is sampling from an inverse Wishart distribution.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not directly answer your question, the following provides an alternative procedure to produce random numbers according to a random MVND.

Consider $n$ independent random variables distributed according to the standard normal ($\mu=0$,$\sigma=1$), $G_j$. Your can form $n$ random variables 
$$X_i = \mu_i +\sum_{j=1}^n\,a_{ij}\,G_j$$ 
where $a_{ij}$ are constants. $X_i$ are distributed according to a MVND, with covariance,
$$ V_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\,a_{jk}$$
The particular MVND is defined by the choice of the elements of the matrix $A$. The full space of possible MVND is sampled with $A$ being an upper (or lower) triangle matrix.

Comment: He's not trying to generate MVND variates.

Comment: The words "generate instances for a data stream" suggest that he might. Real friendly here.

Comment: (I didn't downvote you.)